# creating virtualenv error message

Tags: python, pyramid

The pyramid documentation says:

1. "It is best practice to install Pyramid into a 'virtual' Python environment in order to obtain isolation from any 'system' packages you’ve got installed in your Python version"
2. to install a Virtual Python Enviroment, I have to install setuptools, it worked
3. to create a Virtual Python Enviroment, I have to run  "virtualenv --no-site-packages env"
4. after saying the command, it says "If you’re on UNIX, do not use sudo to run the virtualenv script"

On 3, I ran the command, got permission denied and used sudo. I don't know if the using sudo part is going to be a problem, because I'm not sure if Linux is a kind of Unix.

Now, how to create a virtual python enviroment after seeing this message?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.5.1', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/virtualenv.py", line 558, in main
    prompt=options.prompt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/virtualenv.py", line 647, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/virtualenv.py", line 931, in install_python
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1141, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: How did you fix this one?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are in a directory that you can create files and folders in, e.g.:

```
cd # Go to your home directory
virtualenv --no-site-packages env # Create virtualenv
```

Comment: Also, do not run `virtualenv` as root.

Comment: how could you go to a directory created by other user. i get permission denied.
i use user to login to VPS. But i create a web folder in panel host management (it know as another user).
So from host, i can't cd to that folder -> permission denied

Answer (score 0):

As somebody already said, you need to start the `virtualenv` without `sudo`.

This is what worked for me.

Answer (score -4):

after installing setuptools and running "virtualenv --no-site-package" you didnt actually install virtualenv

so first you must install virtualenv (you must be root for this):

```
$ easy_install virtualenv
```

then just do:

```
$ virtualenv --no-site-package myVirtualEnv
    New python executable in myVirtualEnv/bin/python
    Installing setuptools............done.
```

also linux is a unix like system (to answer your question if "Linux is a kind of Unix").
here you will find out more about unix-like systems - [wikipedia-Unix-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like)

Comment: "OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied" this problem? again. you MUST BE ROOT!